# Copy one child's data into another with Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function where I check whether child A has a child, and if not I want to copy child B into child A.

Currently I'm trying to get a snapshot of B and write it to A. Can't get it work.

I'm a beginner with Swift and Firebase and found similar questions but in other languages which I don't understand.

My code:

```
    ref.child("Users").child("Friends").child(String(a)).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            if(snapshot.hasChild(String(b))){
              //perform operation on node A
            } else {
                 //Here I want to copy DefaultFriends->x into Users->Friends->x
                //perform operation on node A
         } else {
            //Here I want to copy entire DefaultFriends into Users->Friends
            //perform operation on node A
        }
    })
```

My database is structured:

```
    ----Users 
    ---------Friends

    //e.g put Child B here

    ----------------2
    -------------------Friend21
    -------------------Friend22

    ---DefaultFriends 
    -------------------1 //Child B
    ---------------------DefaultFriend11
    ---------------------DefaultFriend12
    -------------------2
    ---------------------DefaultFriend21
    ---------------------DefaultFriend22
    ---------------------DefaultFriend23
    ---------------------DefaultFriend24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly works to just write a snapshot.value to a child

Solution in Swift:

```
   func copy(a:Int, b:Int){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child(String(a)).child(String(b)).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        ref.child("Users").child("Friends").child(String(a)).child(String(b)).setValue(snapshot.value)
    }
}
```